# Hooking system calls for a specific process on Linux

Tags: linux, kernel

I want to make it so that syscalls from a *particular* process are controlled by another process (admin or same user, doesn't really matter to me.) I realize this gives some rootkit trojan vibes, but I'm not actually making malware; I just need an extra level of control over a specific process, not all of them. I also don't want to have to redefine every syscall (just, like `read`, `write`, `connect` and a couple more.)

What I don't want:

- one of those big rootkits that highjack the syscall table inside the kernel's memory.
- anything like `LD_PRELOAD`

I'd rather not have to, like, use `ptrace` to make all instances of `0x0f 0x05` instead jump to some fancy shellcode (especially because that shellcode would be communicating over UDP with another computer.)

Any help would be much appreciated. Everything online about syscall highjacking just shows some source code to rewrite the syscall table.